# Mystery Element in Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I have a very simple layout in android, but I am seeing something I cannot identify and I'm hoping someone has seen it and knows how to remove it.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Main">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Attached is a screenshot showing the element I cannot identify (crudely highlighted), which appears both in vertical and horizontal orientations.  This element is not visible in the designer, only at runtime:

[Screenshot showing mystery element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry65d.png)

My question is how can I force my layout to extend to fill the screen/cover this element?  I am currently using a trial of Xamarin Studio 5.10.2 (build 56).

Comment: Those must be the navigation buttons

Comment: You launched on emulator?

Comment: Navigation buttons?  What would cause them to be drawn in my layout?

Comment: No, this is on a physical device.

Comment: Since I am using a Xamarin trial, I get a splash screen stating that this build will only work for 24 hours....this element is visible on that screen also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly declare your Activity's theme or at runtime to have full screen.

Read @
http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: I have specified the theme both in my activity class and in the manifest, neither of which had an effect.

Comment: Or you can request it at runtime, by adjusting your LayoutParams. Try reading about immersive mode.

Comment: I will do so, but I wasn't looking for a full screen layout.  At this point however, if it works...

Comment: OK, Immersive Mode works in that the mystery element is not initially shown, but as soon as the user swipes to display the status bar, for example, the element is visible again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to simply create a new project and move all of my code into the new project.  Doing so remedied whatever was causing the navigation buttons to display as they did.